# setting the image as well as div width according to the size of screen

Tags: jquery, css, html, background-image

I am using a div whose dimensions are set using jquery, but i wish to show an image in that div and i also want the image to resize accordingly to fit in the div exactly.

How can this be done ???

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like? What don't you know how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery to handle the parameters of a DIV element, then you could use the same method to handle the height/width of the image. You could try something like:

```
var MyImg = document.getElementById(img_id);
var Div = document.getElementById(div_id);
document.MyImg.style.height = document.Div.style.height;
document.MyImg.style.width = document.Div.style.width;
```

If you want to leave a small border, subtract a few pixels from both the height and the width and align the image centrally both horizontally and vertically.

Addon: Alternatively, you couls set CSS attributes to:
    height: auto;
    width: auto;

I had understood you wanted to use jQuery, my bad...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the image as the background of the div and set the `background-size` to `100%`:

```
background: url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
```

Working example (play with the div width if you'd like):

http://jsfiddle.net/KWKuG/

Answer (score 0):

You can set a maximum width and height of 100% on the image with CSS:

```
img {
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;  
}
```

This way, you will maintain the image's aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you really want to skew the image like that, but you can just set that with css.

```
#yourDiv img { width: 100%; height: 100%}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Shx3z/1/